# When should I instantiate the children class?

Tags: php, oop, parent

Let's says I have 3 items : a keyboard, a tshirt and a bottle of cola.

```
$keyboard = new Item("Keyboard");
echo $keyboard->getPrice(); // return 50;

$tshirt = new Item("Tshirt");
echo $tshirt->getPrice(); // return 20;

$cola = new Item("Cola");
echo $cola->getPrice(); // return 0 or 2 whether the bottle is empty or not.
```

What is the best practice to get the `Price` of the bottle of cola ?

I started by creating 2 classes :

```
Class Item {
    $this->price;

    function __construct($name) {
    // ...
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }
}

Class Bottle extends Item {
    $this->empty;

    function __construct($name) {
    // get from database the value of $this->empty
    }
    public function getPrice() {
        if($this->empty)
            return 0;
        else 
            return $this->price;
    }
}
```

But now I'm wondering ; when I use : `$cola = new Item("Cola");`, I'm instantiating an `Item` object and not a `Bottle` object, because I don't know yet if it's a "normal" item or a bottle.

Should I instead instantiating a Bottle object and research for another logic in my application ? Or is there a way to "recreate" the item object and transforms it as a bottle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect example of when to use the [Factory Pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php).

For your code, you could do something like this.

```
class ItemFactory {
    // we don't need a constructor since we'll probably never have a need
    // to instantiate it.
    static function getItem($item){
        if ($item == "Coke") {
            return new Bottle($item);
        } else if ( /* some more of your items here */){
            /*code to return object extending item*/
        } else { 
            // We don't have a definition for it, so just return a generic item.
            return new Item($item);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like `$item = ItemFactory::getItem($yourvar)`

The Factory Pattern is useful when you have a lot of objects that have the same base (or parent) class, and you need to determine what class they are at runtime.

Comment: +1 for factory, but link is down so : http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx